# Finding the relative path of a text file from a different subfolder

Tags: python-3.x, unix

I have a parent directory and my python code is in one subdirectory but my input file is in another subdirectory. How do I find the relative path of the input file? This is what I have right now but it gives me this error - `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

```
    dirc = os.path.dirname("..")
    filename = os.path.join(dirc,"/input/input_file.txt")


    f =  open(filename, "r")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems to ask how to obtain the absolute path of a Unix file in python. It says relative path, but according to the code, the relative path is known and is `../input/input_file.txt`. The task at hand as explained in the question does not require that and would be easily accomplished just using relative paths that are known according to the premise (see **note** below). However, since the main question is about finding absolute paths and using this to solve the issue, that is what I will answer.

You have two problems in your code.

1. `os.path.dirname()` does not return the absolute path that you are looking for. Instead, it returns the directory component of the paths given, which, in this case is the empty string (as the path you give only contains a file (`..` counts as a file). You will want to use `os.path.abspath()` instead.
2. `os.path.join()` disregards all elements that come before the last absolute path. Since `"/input/input_file.txt"` has the form of an absolute path (starting with `/`), it will disregard `dirc`. You will want to supply relative paths to this function without leading slash.

Altogether:

```
import os
dirc = os.path.abspath("..")
filename = os.path.join(dirc, "input/input_file.txt")
f =  open(filename, "r")
print([line for line in f])
f.close()
```

**Note** that you do not need the absolute path. You will achive the same by doing:

```
f =  open("../input/input_file.txt", "r")
print([line for line in f])
f.close()
```